filetype not set for current buffer after restoring session with persistence.nvim
I have an autocmd like this one to restore a session using persistence.nvim, but after doing so the filetype for the current buffer is not set (preventing features like syntax highlighting). filetypes for other buffers are fine.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("VimEnter", {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("persistence", { clear = true }),
  callback = function()
    require("persistence").load()
  end,
})


I found the answer here which is to add nested = true to the autocmd like so:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("VimEnter", {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("persistence", { clear = true }),
  callback = function()
    require("persistence").load()
  end,
  nested = true,
})

